# Prevent a command output from being displayed in a pager

Tags: apt, pager

Some commands display their output in a pager, and don't return. Here is an example of such a command :

`apt changelog zsh`

From the `man apt` page:

```
changelog
    changelog downloads a package changelog and displays it through sensible-pager. The server name and
    base directory is defined in the APT::Changelogs::Server variable (e. g.
    http://packages.debian.org/changelogs for Debian or http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs for
    Ubuntu). By default it displays the changelog for the version that is installed. However, you can
    specify the same options as for the install command.
```

...But nothing anywhere about passing options to said `sensible-pager`, or use another one.

How can I get, say, the N first lines of it, of better yet, parse the output to extract the information I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pipe the changelog information to a different command like this:

```
$ apt changelog pkg_name | some_command
```

Or you can store the contents to a file like this:

```
$ apt changelog pkg_name > file.log
```

But it is going to show this warning:

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

Comment: In fact I did that, but the command was taking so long to return that I though I didn't work :|